# php, $sql returning empty $rows before using $result

Tags: php

I'm new to stackoverflow, please don't rush on me :)

I'm struggling with this for few days now:

```
    <?php
                require_once "../../config.php";
                $sql = "SELECT chestionar.participanti.id, chestionar.participanti.id_chestionar, chestionar.participanti.email, chestionar.participanti.nume
FROM chestionar.participanti WHERE chestionar.participanti.email LIKE '$email' LIMIT 1";
                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                        echo "<thead>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<th>IDClient</th>";
                        echo "<th>IDChestionar</th>";
                        echo "<th>Adresa</th>";
                        echo "<th>Nume</th>";
                        echo "<th>Actiuni</th>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        echo "</thead>";
                        echo "<tbody>";
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['id_chestionar'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['nume'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>";
                            echo "<a href='deletech.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' title='Sterge Client' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
                            echo "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        echo "</tbody>";
                        echo "</table>";
                        mysqli_free_result($result);
                    } else {
                        echo "<p class='lead'><em>No client.</em></p>";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                }

                mysqli_close($link);
                ?>
```

Before anything is inserted into

```
<form action="" method="GET">
            <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="search">&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" value="Search Client" name="btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
        </form>
```

it return all rows from db, but empty.
The search works. And this "anomaly" does not apply to the other db's. Same server/same mysql. 
Thanks.

Comment: Where you can define $email?

Comment: Before HTML: if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']));
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']));
}

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I will update it later to prepared statement. At the moment I use .htaccess with 
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from "LAN or one IPPUBLIC"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for whoever posted.
I found the problem, which was empty/null rows on selected columns.
Once I've deleted those null rows, the problem disappeared.